# A vector bisects the angle between two vectors

Tags: geometry

Find the vector C for which C bisects the angle between the two vectors A and B where $A = (2, -3 ,6) , B = (-1 , 2 ,-2)$
And the norm of C = $3\sqrt{42}$
My turn :
Let
$$ C = (x ,y,z) $$ then
$$\frac{2x -3y + 6z }{7} = \frac{-x + 2y -2z }{3}$$ ,
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 378$$
But now i have 2 equations with 3 variables ?!

Comment: **HINT**: Solve the system of linear equations. You'll get one free variable. Then choose the value of that variable to make the norm of $C$ come out correct.

Comment: Note that the plane that the two vectors and their bisector are in is $6x+2y=z$. Via dot product, $\cos\theta=-1$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. This implies that the vectors are on a straight line, so the bisector must be perpendicular to both. In other words, we want $2x-3y+6z=0$ and $6x+2y=z$. Those two, with your third equation, give the answer desired.

Comment: This is not a good approach because it doesn’t take the original orientations of the vectors into account. The equation that you’ve written down is for the _acute_ bisector of the two planes, but the angle between the two vectors is in fact obtuse, so the normal to the plane described by your equation doesn’t have the right direction. Even if it did, there’s a sign ambiguity and you have to examine $A$ and $B$ to determine which choice of sign is correct. The better approach is to compute the bisector directly, as described in the answers you’ve gotten so far.

Answer (score 8):

It's simpler to do some geometry: the normalised vectors $\vec A_\text{norm}=\dfrac{\vec A}{\|\vec A\|}$ and  $\vec B_\text{norm}=\dfrac{\vec B}{\|\vec B\|}$ define a rhombus, so $\vec A_\text{norm}+\vec B_\text{norm}$ is a directing vector of the bisector.
Now $\|\vec A\|=\sqrt{4+9+36}=7$, and similarly $\|\vec B\|=3$, so 
$$\vec C=\lambda\Bigl(\frac1{7}(2,-3,6)+\frac13(-1,2,-2)\Bigr).$$
Can you continue and determine $\lambda$ so that the condition on the norm is satisfied?

Comment: Oh! yes. I'll fix that within seconds. Thank you for pointing it!

Answer (score 2):

Unit vector along the angle bisector of two given vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is given by $$\hat c=\frac{1}{2}\sec \frac{\theta}{2}(\hat a+\hat b)$$ 
$$\hat a=\frac{2\hat i-3\hat j+6\hat k}{7};\hat b=\frac{-\hat i+2\hat j-2\hat k}{3};\cos \theta=-\frac{20}{21};\sec \frac{\theta}{2}=\sqrt{42}$$

Substituting in above 
$$\hat c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{42}}(-\hat i+5\hat j+4\hat k)$$

$$\vec c=3(-\hat i+5\hat j+4\hat k)$$

$$C=(-3,15,12)$$